# Как исправить резкое появление javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, ecmascript-6

Div резко появляется (свойство transition не отрабатывается).
Свойство visibility не очень нравится(т.к только скрывает элемент).
Делать opcaity `setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;

},0);` - по мне тоже не очень.

```js
document.getElementById("block").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    hidden_picture.style.display="block";
    hidden_picture.style.opacity="1"; 
    hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#hidden_picture {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(47,90,128,0.3);
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
#block {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #8FACC5;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden_picture"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала указать, что это block, а после этого отключить прозрачность.

```js
let hidden_picture = document.getElementById("hidden_picture");
setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.display="block";  
},50);

let hidden_picture1 = document.getElementById("hidden_picture");
setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;   
},60);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#hidden_picture {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(47,90,128,0.3);
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden_picture"></div>
```

Comment: Делать opcaity setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;

},0); - по мне тоже не очень.

Comment: Появляется ненужная задержка

Comment: Задержка в тысячные доли секунды не будет заметна человеческому глазу.
Ответ верный, отвечает на вопрос

Comment: Там можно использовать 0 задержку. Перечитайте вопрос

Comment: а когда и как он должен появиться? объясни? чтобы был понятен конечный результат?

Comment: Переписал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

display: none;  на transition не срабатывает надо использовать opacity

```js
let hidden_picture = document.getElementById("hidden_picture");
setTimeout(()=> {
  hidden_picture.style.opacity="1";
   
},1000);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#hidden_picture {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(47,90,128,0.3);
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden_picture"></div>
```

Comment: В реальном проекте не получилось  present_0.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    hidden_picture.style.display="block";
    hidden_picture.style.opacity="1"; 
    hidden_picture.style.opacity=1;  
    img.src="pic/Variants.webp";
    img.style.width="70%";
    img.style.height="auto";
});

Comment: Всё равно резко

Comment: Если ещё что можешь предложить, напиши. Буду очень благодараен.

Comment: display: none; на transition не срабатывает надо использовать opacity

let hidden_picture = document.getElementById("hidden_picture");

Comment: Все что под блоком не вделяется

Comment: При включенном display

Comment: Letton, тебе надо что-бы он медленно появлялся? Ну  прости, я не понимаю, что да как ты хочешь...  Что касается ответов и я и Юрий правильно решили твою задачу, каждый по своему, ну опиши ты в вопросе как именно и что надо...

Comment: Переписал вопрос